# Bulk cancel deployment SharePoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, stsadm

Is there and easier way to cancel all WSP files currently being deployed to a SharePoint farm?

I'm currently using the STSAdmin function CancelDeployment but this requires me to run STSAdmin EnumDeployments first and manually copy and paste the job IDs into another script.

I need an easier way to do this, as I might have to ask someone else to run the script, and I'm having to run the script a couple of times a day myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could easily modify the "Get-Installed-Farm-Solutions.ps1" script found here on CodePlex: http://www.codeplex.com/SharePointPSScripts/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=21806